# Custom Filter Function with Predicate using List Comprehension

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

I need to develop my own filter function similar to how `filter` works in Haskell but by using list comprehension and a predicate. So I would put `lcFilter (>3) [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,444,3]` in ghci and it would print all numbers greater than 3.

My code is based on a recursion example which I'm good at but I can't seem to convert to list comprehension. It seams no matter what I put in `[x | x<-xs, p]` it always throws a compiler error. I know the `p` part is wrong. I've tried `==p`, `xs==p` and just about everything else I could think of. This makes me think some other part might be wrong but I'm really not sure.

Here is the code for my function `lcFilter`. I'm not sure if some or all of it is wrong so I'm posting the whole thing.

```
lcFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
lcFilter _ [] = []
lcFilter p (x:xs) = [x | x<-xs, p]
```

If I type `lcFilter (>3) [1,2,3,4,5]` it should print `[4,5]` just like the standard Haskell `filter` function.

Comment: "it always throws a compiler error" should be followed by the full error message. Posting the errors you get is very useful to potential answerers. Please remember that for future questions.

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as

```
      [x | x <- xs, p x]
```

Since `p :: a -> Bool`, and `xs :: [a]`, to get a Boolean we need to *apply* the function to an argument; and by the list comprehension semantics we have `x :: a`.

The *application* rule of type inference is

```
            x :: a
          p   :: a -> b
         ---------------
          p x ::      b
```

And you don't need the pattern matching, list comprehension will take care of that.

So overall, it is

```
lcFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
lcFilter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p]
```

---

List comprehensions are fun. One rule they follow is

```
    [ ... | x <- (xs            ++                ys), .... ]  ===
    [ ... | x <-  xs, ....  ]   ++   [ ... | x <- ys , .... ]
```

As a consequence, we also have

```
    [ ... | x <- ([y]           ++                ys), .... ]  ===
    [ ... | x <-  [y], .... ]   ++   [ ... | x <- ys , .... ]  ===
    [ ...{x/y} | ....{x/y}  ]   ++   [ ... | x <- ys , .... ]
```

where `{x/y}` means *"replace `x` by `y` throughout"*. Thus, a list `[a,b,...,n]` is transformed by your definition into

```
    [  a,           b,          ...,    n        ]             ===>
    [  a | p a] ++ [b | p b] ++ ... ++ [n | p n  ]
```

This can be further understood in terms of / serve as a nice illustration to / the concepts of *monads*, or of *monoids*, but we'll leave that for another day. :)