# List Comprehension: Even numbers from 0 to x

Tags: list, function, haskell, filter, list-comprehension

I'm currently learning Haskell and I must say, I am having a terrible time.

I've been tasked with the exercise of creating a function, evens, which takes a value, `x`, and returns a list of all even values from `0` to `x`.

For example:

> ```
> >  evens 10
>
> > [2,4,6,8,10]
> ```

I have been attempting to modify some example functions using list comprehension to achieve my goal however I have simply been riddled with errors, worse even I've tried so many things everything is one big confusing blur.

My last attempt went as follows:

```
evens :: int -> [int]
evens n = [x | x <- [0..n], filter even x]
```

It produced the error:

> ex1.hs:9:29: error:
>
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
>
> • In the expression: `filter even x`
>
> In a stmt of a list comprehension: `filter even x`
>
> In the expression: `[x | x <- [0 .. n], filter even x]`

I do see its expecting a Boolean but quite frankly I don't understand where or why.

Any help would be largely appreciated. I have never had any experience with functional programming languages and I am having a hard time figuring out my errors in thought. I feel like I've overthought this one simple question to a point beyond belief.

Comment: A boolean expression in a list comprehension is already treated as a filter.  You don't need to say `filter even x`, you just say `even x`.  Also the language is case sensitive, make sure you say `Int` instead of `int` in your type signature.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  [List comprehensions are fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215405/custom-filter-function-with-predicate-using-list-comprehension/56215421#56215421). :)

Comment: Not worth writing an answer for but no-one has told you the nicest solution yet: `evens n = [0,2..n]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the word `filter` from that code.

The `Boolean` that is expected is `even x`. When this value is `True`, `x` will be included in the output list.

`filter` is a *list*-creating function, but the list comprehension is already creating a list, itself.

In fact, `filter p` could be coded as

```
filter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p x]
```

So using `filter` on the inside is quite redundant.

---

About that error message. You say

> I do see its expecting a Boolean but quite frankly I don't understand where or why.

But the error message shows us *where*:

> ex1.hs:9:29: error:
>
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
>
> • In the expression: `filter even x`

This is where. It is the most immediate culprit: the expression `filter even x`. It is *its* actual type, `[Integer]`, that does not match the expected type, `Bool`.

> In a stmt of a list comprehension: `filter even x`

That expression appears <s>in</s> as a <s>"stmt"</s> statement in our list comprehension,

> In the expression: `[x | x <- [0 .. n], filter even x]`

which is the above full expression. So we just need to read those messages *inside-out*, to find our way to the (immediate) place of the error.

---

So from the context of the list comprehension, `[ r | x <- xs, q]`, the `q` is expected to have the type `Bool`.

But in itself, `q = filter even x` has type `[Integer]`, the list of integers.

Why? Because (with the simplified, non-polymorphic types as pertinent to this context)

```
  filter      :: (Integer -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
         even :: (Integer -> Bool)
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  filter even ::                      [Integer] -> [Integer]
              xs                   :: [Integer]
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  filter even xs                                :: [Integer]
```

(read `::` as "has type"); whereas

```
  even   :: (Integer -> Bool)
       x ::  Integer
  ---------------------------
  even x             :: Bool
```

---

And if you're wondering why it's `Integer` even though you wrote `int`, the short answer to that is, `int` is a *type variable* just like `a` or `b` or `t` or ... . It is not a *type*, like `Int`. So you get the default which, here, is `Integer`.

Comment: I think there is more going on here. You have used `xs :: [Integer]` but OP has `x :: Int`. And infact `:t filter even (1::Int)` complains: "Couldn't match `[a]` with `Int`, whereas `:t filter even (1::_)` reports `1` to be of type `[a]`. A newcomer might be very confused that the number 1 is accepted by Haskell as a list (of type `[a]`). Maybe one should discuss this topic in a separate question but I want to point that out for future readers.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann uh, I think I understand your comment now. you probably referred to the `x` in `filter even x` in the OP's code, which type is known as `x :: Integer` (or `Int`, whatever) from the context; but when I show the type derivation I derive the type of the expression `filter even xs` *"in itself"*, i.e. just from the type of `filter` and `even` -- to follow the error message. GHC *could* choose your approach, to focus on the `x` instead of `filter even x`, then say "by LC `x` is known to be `Int`, but `filter even` expects `[a]`" ....

Comment: Yes. (Curiously in `evens :: a -> [a]; evens n =  [x | x <- "", filter even x]` the compiler gives a second warning (`[Integer]` doesn't match with `Char`), but it doesn't in ` evens :: a -> [a]; evens n =  [x | x <- [0], filter even x]`).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative but also correct formulation would be,

```
Prelude> filter (\x -> even x) [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

You can also drop the lambda function here and do

```
Prelude> filter even [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

More succinctly, in the list-comprehension format.

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [1..10], even x]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Comment: `\x -> even x` is equivalent to `even` in this context.

Comment: yes, that is an equivalent function but for a haskell noobie, I think it's a little more clear what is going on when you express it as a lambda

Comment: If anything, I think it implies a difference between a function defined by the expression and the original function that simply doesn't exist.