# How does `[ (x !! 0, x !! 1) | x <- mapM (const ['A', 'B', 'C'] ) [1..2], head x < head (tail x) ]` work?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am new to Haskell and wondering how the statement

```hs
[ (x !! 0, x !! 1) | x <- mapM (const ['A', 'B', 'C'] ) [1..2], head x < head (tail x) ]
```

works. (I found it on StackOverflow.) I know what it outputs, but I am not really understanding it.

Comment: I think you are "starting too high". The above example needs basic understanding of *monads* (used by `mapM`), and how lists are monads. Furthermore it is also quite ugly and not really idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: I agree, do you have an alternative Solution? I need the output `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]` for the input `['A', 'B', 'C']`

Comment: So you're looking for unique combinations. You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602474/function-to-generate-the-unique-combinations-of-a-list-in-haskell

Comment: You said, you found it on StackOverflow, could you please edit your post and add the link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the above expression is likely not what is considered *idiomatic* Haskell. Probably a better version would be:

```
[ (x0, x1) | (x0:x1:_) <- mapM (const "ABC") [1..2], x0 < x1 ]
```

This is cleaner and if the lists in the `mapM (const "ABC")` would return a list that contains less than two elements (that is here impossible), it will not error.

Probably the core problem here is to understand how `mapM` works. The expression `mapM (const "ABC") [1..2]` boils down to:

```
mapM (\_ -> "ABC") [1..2]
```

since we do not take the values of the list into account, it is equivalent to:

```
replicateM 2 "ABC"
```

This `replicateM` for `2` can be rewritten as (pseudo-Haskell syntax):

```
replicateM 2 :: [a] -< [[a]]
replicateM 2 l = do
    x0 <- l
    x1 <- l
    return [x0, x1]
```

or if we desugar this:

```
replicateM 2 l = l >>= \x0 -> l >>= \x1 -> return [x0, x1]
```

For a list, the instance of `Monad` is implemented as:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    (>>=) = flip concatMap
```

so that means that for a list this `replicateM 2`, is implemented as:

```
replicateM 2 l :: [a] -> [[a]]
replicateM 2 l = concatMap (\x0 -> concatMap (\x1 -> [[x0, x1]]) l) l
```

or simpler:

```
replicateM 2 l :: [a] -> [[a]]
replicateM 2 l = concatMap (\x0 -> map (\x1 -> [x0, x1]) l) l
```

we thus make all possible combinations of two items of the list. This thus means that:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> replicateM 2 "ABC"
["AA","AB","AC","BA","BB","BC","CA","CB","CC"]
```

We then use this in list comprehension, and for each of these sublists with two elements, we check if the first element `x0` is smaller than the second element with the *filter part* in the list comprehension (`x0 < x1`). If that is the case, we yield these elements as a 2-tuple.

It thus creates 2-tuples for each two items in `"ABC"`, if the first element is (strictly) smaller than the second one.

Here we however do a bit "too much work": more than half of the elements will be rejected. We can optimize this by making use of [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails):

```
import Data.List(tails)

[(x0, x1) | (x0:xs) <- tails "ABC", x1 <- xs ]
```

which yields the same value:

```
Prelude Control.Monad Data.List> [(x0, x1) | (x0:xs) <- tails "ABC", x1 <- xs ]
[('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','C')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the question of how the original code works, and skipping straight to how to write this more idiomatically, start with `myList = ['A', 'B', 'C']`.

You can get a list of *all* the possible pairs; pick an `x`, pick a `y`, and put them in a tuple:

```
> [ (x, y) | x <- myList, y <- myList ]
[('A','A'),('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','A'),('B','B'),('B','C'),('C','A'),('C','B'),('C','C')]
```

But you only want the ones where `x < y`:

```
> [ (x, y) | x <- myList, y <- myList, x < y ]
[('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-writing it according to the definition `mapM f xs = sequence (map f xs)`, we get

```
[ (x !! 0, x !! 1) | x <- mapM (const ['A', 'B', 'C'] ) [1..2], head x < head (tail x) ]
=
[ (a, b) | [a,b] <- mapM (const "ABC" ) [1,2], a < b ]
=
[ (a, b) | [a,b] <- sequence ["ABC" | _ <- [1,2]], a < b ]
=
[ (a, b) | [a,b] <- sequence ["ABC", "ABC"], a < b ]
=
[ (a, b) | [a,b] <- [[a,b] | a <- "ABC", b <- "ABC"], a < b ]   -- by def of sequence
=
[ (a, b) | a <- "ABC", b <- "ABC", a < b ]                 -- by associativity of (++)
=
[ (a, b) | a <- "ABC", b <- [b | b <- "ABC", b > a] ]      -- by associativity of (++)
=
[ (a, b) | a <- "A", b <- [b | b <- "ABC", b > a] ]
   ++
   [ (a, b) | a <- "B", b <- [b | b <- "ABC", b > a] ]
     ++
     [ (a, b) | a <- "C", b <- [b | b <- "ABC", b > a] ]
=
[ (a, b) | a <- "A", b <- [b | b <- "BC"] ]                -- by pre-evaluation
   ++
   [ (a, b) | a <- "B", b <- [b | b <- "C"] ]
     ++
     [ ]
=
[ (a, b) | a <- "A", b <- "BC" ]
   ++
   [ (a, b) | a <- "B", b <- "C" ]
=
[ (a, b) | (a:bs) <- ["ABC", "BC"], b <- bs ]
```

See? [*List comprehensions are fun*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215421/849891). You could play this game too, and find out the answer that way.

Monadic `do` notation is fun too, and can be written as Monad Comprehensions, which for lists looks and is exactly the same as List Comprehensions.