# How does mapM work with const functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, constants, combinations, monads, map-function

as I had been looking for ways to optimize a password cracker I had been making, I came across a much shorter implementation of all possible character combinations in a list, which used this function:

```
mapM (const xs) [1..n]
```

where `xs` could be the characters available, and `n` the length of the desired words.
so

```
mapM (const "abcd") [1..4]
```

would output a list `["aaaa","aaab","aaac","aaad","aaba","aabb"..]` and so on. Only the length matters for the list of th right, I could have written `['f','h','s','e']` or any 4 element list instead.

I can see why the list doesn't matter, it's passed to a `const` function. I can see that `const` of a list technically satisfies `(a -> m a)`.

But my question is: why isn't the output simply `["abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"]`, or maybe `"abcdabcdabcdabcd"`? What does a `const` function do to output all 4 letter variations for the given letters?

Comment: The answer to your question is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590761/1248563

Comment: Equivalent way of doing it: `replicateM 4 "abcd"`.

Comment: A list is an instance of `Monad`, `mapM`. You can however use `replicateM` here: `replicateM 4 ['a' .. 'z']` for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can understand `mapM` using this intuition:

```
mapM f [x1, x2, ..., xN]
=
do y1 <- f x1
   y2 <- f x2
   ...
   yN <- f xN
   return [y1, y2, ..., yN]
```

In your case:

```
mapM (const "abcd") [1 .. 4]
=
do y1 <- const "abcd" 1
   y2 <- const "abcd" 2
   y3 <- const "abcd" 3
   y4 <- const "abcd" 4
   return [y1, y2, y3, y4]
=
do y1 <- "abcd"
   y2 <- "abcd"
   y3 <- "abcd"
   y4 <- "abcd"
   return [y1, y2, y3, y4]
```

The latter is equivalent to a list comprehension

```
[ [y1, y2, y3, y4] | y1<-"abcd", y2<-"abcd", y3<-"abcd", y4<-"abcd"]
```

which will produce your output.

Comment: I never saw the do notation with lists before. It's a bit counter-intuitive first, but at the end you realize this is brillant !!!

Answer (score 4):

(This answer assumes [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) instead of `mapM`, but the two functions are largely equivalent. `mapM` exists mainly for historical reasons.)

Haskell lists can be seen from two different points of view. On one hand, they are a data structure that contains values. On the other hand, they represent a *nondeterminism effect*. Nondeterminism not in the sense of generating random values, but in the sense of *having multiple possible alternatives for a value*.

Now, imagine we have two "nondeterministic `Int`s" (namely, two lists of `Int`s). What if we want to sum them? What does it *mean* to sum two nondeterministic `Int`s?

The answer is provided by the `Applicative` instance of `[]`, in particular the [`liftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:liftA2) function that lets us promote a function that combines `Int`s to a function that combines nondeterministic `Int`s. Giving it a more concrete signature than it really has:

```
liftA2 ::  (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

But what does it do? Basically it applies the function *to all possible combinations*:

```
ghci> liftA2 (+) [1,2] [5,7]
[6,8,7,9]
```

There's also a [`liftA3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:liftA3) that does the same for a ternary function and three nondeterministic values.

Now, what if we had a whole container of regular values, and mapped it with a function that returned nondeterministic values? We would need to combine the produced values for *all* elements in the container, not just two or three like the `liftAX` functions do. There's a different function called `traverse` which does the job. It only works for some containers, those that have a [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable) instance.

And here's a possible source of confusion. In your example, lists are working both as effects (instances of `Applicative`) and as containers which can be mapped with an effectful function (instances of `Traversable`).

To make it less confusing, let us create our own traversable container different from `[]`:

```
data Triad a = Triad a a a deriving (Show,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)
```

And invoke `traverse` like in the example:

```
traverse (const "abcd") (Triad 1 2 3)
```

What do we get? Something like:

```
[Triad 'a' 'a' 'a',Triad 'a' 'a' 'b',Triad 'a' 'a' 'c',...
```

Which could be seen either as a list of `Triad`s, or as a non-deterministic `Triad` resulting from combining the nondeterminism effects of `const "abcd" 1`, `const "abcd" 2` and `const "abcd" 3` using the `Applicative` instance of `[]`.

**Note**: because `Triad` always has three components, this would be equivalent to `liftA3 Triad (const "abcd" 1) (const "abcd" 2) (const "abcd" 3)` using [`liftA3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:liftA3).

It's also equivalent to `sequenceA (Triad (const "abcd" 1) (const "abcd" 2) (const "abcd" 3))` using [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA). `sequenceA` works with containers whose elements already are "nodetermimistic values".

Answer (score 2):

```
mapM (const xs) [1..n]
 ==
sequence $ map (const xs) [1..n]
 ==
sequence [xs | _ <- [1..n]]
 ==
sequence $ replicate n xs
 ==
replicateM n xs
```

and by definition

```
sequence [xs | _ <- [1..n]]        -- n >= 1
 ==
[(x:ys) | x <- xs ,
          ys <- sequence [xs | _ <- [1..n-1]]]
```

thus

```
sequence [xs | _ <- [1..n]]
 ==
[ [x1,x2,...,xn] | x1 <- xs, x2 <- xs, ..., xn <- xs]
```

So what gives it the special meaning is not the `const` function but actually the definition of `Monad` for lists, which induces the meaning of `sequence` for lists.

Monads can be said to be [generalized nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20monad%20nested) (among many other things), and list monad is just that, [nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178620/849891), no generalization. It can be seen in the list comprehension illustration above.

For lists, `do` notation and list comprehensions are the same. There are even monad comprehensions, that look like list comprehensions, for any monad. The `do` and `<-` are just notation, could have been written `for` and `in` just the same. Imagine seeing

```
for x1 in "abcd":
  for x2 in "abcd":
     for x3 in "abcd":
        yield [x1,x2,x3]
```

as *valid Haskell*.