# How to interpret a Traversable type as an Applicative in this function?

Tags: list, haskell, cartesian-product, traversable

I was experimenting with haskell classes, and I discovered that (at least some) `Traversable` data structures are also `Applicative`

And when you look at the definition of `Traversable`, you see that it can be defined with the `sequenceA` function:

```hs
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

And since *list* is both `Traversable` and `Applicative`, I did try to use sequenceA on a list of lists:

```hs
-- this thing ...
sequenceA [[0, 1], [7, 8, 9]]

-- is evaluated as [[0,7],[0,8],[0,9],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9]]
```

And I get the cartesian product of the 2 lists!

And it even works for a bigger number of lists.

---

What is it the case?

What is the intuition behind the behaviour of this function?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64542331/1364288

Comment: @danidiaz Nice! Looks like a completely straightforward exact duplicate to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner The other question has a less informative title though, because the "const" is pretty unrelated to what is really happening.

Comment: @danidiaz That's okay. The StackOverflow stance is that questions that lead to the same answer are duplicates, even if the questions themselves appear different on the surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition for the list applicative is that of nondeterministic computation. You can think of a list of type `[X]` with *n* elements as being a calculation that produces an `X`, and it's definitely one of the *n* choices of `X` contained in that list, but any of them is possible.

For example, the list `['a','e']` represents a calculation that could produce `'a'` or could produce `'e'`. The list `[-4,4]` might be the result of asking about the square root of `16`. The list `[]` is a nondeterministic calculation that can't correctly produce any value! (Say, the result of asking about the real square root of `-16`...)

In this interpretation, when we have a list of functions `fs` and some values `xs`, the list `fs <*> xs` is the list of all the possible results you could get by applying any of the functions in `fs` to any of the arguments in `xs`. Meanwhile, the list `pure x` is the deterministic calculation that always produces exactly one result, namely, `x`.

So! If you have a nested list, then there are various alternative ways of thinking about what it means, including that it is a list of nondeterministic calculations or that it is a nondeterministic calculation that produces lists as its result. The `sequenceA` function transports you between these representations: it takes a list of nondeterministic calculations and produces a single nondeterministic calculation whose result is a list. So:

```
 [[a,b,c],[d,e],[f,g,h,i]]
```

You can think of this as a list with three elements. The first is a choice between `a`, `b`, and `c`, the second is a choice between `d` and `e`, and the third is a choice between `f`, `g`, `h`, and `i`. The `sequenceA` function will produce a nondeterministic choice of lists, each of which has the same shape as the outer list above; that is, each list we are choosing between will have length 3. The first element will come from `[a,b,c]`; the second will come from `[d,e]`, and the third from `[f,g,h,i]`. If you think for a bit about all the ways that could happen, you will see it's exactly their Cartesian product!

Comment: This is great ! But could you add the equivalent with the do notation, I found it really usefull ...

Comment: xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)